# How to insert a value if not duplicated with liquibase?

Tags: mysql, sql, liquibase

I need to convert a MySQL `INSERT IGNORE INTO ...` statement to a `changeSet` in liquibase and I prefer not to insert the statement directly in the `changeSet`.

Since I cannot find a direct translation, I'm wondering how to write a `changeSet` to insert a row only if the primary key part doesn't already exists in another row of the same table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Liquibase doesn't have direct support for `INSERT IGNORE` support. If you are not wanting to use the `<sql>` tag, your only option is to use something like

```
<changeSet>
        <insert ...></insert>
        <modifySql>
             <replace replace="INSERT" with="INSERT IGNORE"/>
         </modifySql>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 1):

With a liquibase 3.2 and oracle12

```
<changeSet>
        <insert ...></insert>
        <modifySql>
             <replace replace="INSERT" with="insert /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index(my_table, my_table_pk) */"/>
         </modifySql>
</changeSet>
```

remarks : 
Not use "replace value"  but "replace replace"

It works too with the changeset loadData